# SQL - Best way to determine Operation Type in Trigger?

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

Below is the code i'm using to determine if the operation in an insert/update/delete.  This question is two part.

One - this is a correct way of determining the operation type.
Two - Is this the best way of determining the operation type.

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ActionType   CHAR (1)

   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
      BEGIN
         SET @ActionType = 'I'
      END

   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
      BEGIN
         SET @ActionType = 'U'
      END

   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
      BEGIN
         SET @ActionType = 'D'
      END

      Select @ActionType;
End
```

Comment: Well, the *best* solution for me is to have **three separate** triggers - one for `INSERT`, one for `DELETE`, and a third for `UPDATE` - then it's clear from the beginning what kind of operation you're dealing with ....

Comment: @marc_s - I agree that would remove ambiguity, but why maintain three triggers if they all perform the same task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One: yes. Two: you can be even more concise than that.

Here is the code I am using currently.

```
SELECT @Action = CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED) 
             AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DELETED) THEN 'U'
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED) THEN 'I'
            ELSE 'D' END;
```